# Command Compile Storyboard failed with nonzero exit code

Tags: swift, xcode, build, compiler-errors, storyboard

I have been getting that error message when ever I try to build my app, I am stuck and unable to develop my app until I get this fixed. I know there is a post similar to this although none of the options have helped me. 
I have tried restarting x-code
Deleting Derived Data folder (when I build the project the derived folder just reappears)
And I have also searched the entire web
Nothing has worked

Answer (score 0):

clean your project Command shift k

Comment: that makes the error go away although as soon as I build the project the error happens again, forgot to mention I have already tried that.

Comment: can u copy whole error message, also what version xcode

Comment: The newest version and now I’m getting a different error message, it says the document main.storyboard could not be opened